# PERL what is next element to $_ in for loop

Tags: perl

I want to compare 2 consecutive elements of loop

```
@arr=qw(1 2 3 3 4);
foreach(@arr)
{
if($_ == $_+1)
  {
  print "yes";
  }
}
```

What should i use instead of $_+1 in this case

Comment: provided that there's a way to get the next value, what would happen when we reach the last 4?

Comment: it will compare with undef value and condition will fail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to loop over indices,

```
my @arr = qw(1 2 3 3 4);
foreach (0 .. $#arr-1) {
  my ($current, $next) = @arr[$_, $_+1];

  if ($current == $next) {
    print "yes";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it the plain old C way:

```
for( my $i=0; $i<@arr-1; $i++ ){
   if( $arr[$i] == $arr[$i+1] ){
      print "yes\n";
   }
}
```

Or in another style:

```
print "Yes\n" for grep{ $arr[$_] == $arr[$_+1] }(0..$#arr-1);
```

Comment: I know this, is there a way using foreach

Answer (score 0):

The FP solution would use `pairwise` from `List::MoreUtils`:

```
pairwise {
    say "yes" if $a == $b;
} @arr @{[ @arr[1..$#arr] ]}
```

(the `@{[ ... ]}` is annoying, but `pairwise` requires a true array and array slices aren't (you can't take references to them)).

(NB: `$b` will be undefined on the last iteration through the array, which may be what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do this with a range-based `foreach` loop, and without dealing with indices.  But instead of looking ahead, you keep track of where you've been; the number you got on the previous iteration. And avoid `print` on the first iteration.

```
{
  my $prev;
  foreach ( @arr ) {
    print "yes ($prev==$_)\n" if defined $prev && $prev == $_;
    $prev = $_;
  }
}
```

This assumes that there are no 'undef' elements in `@arr`.  If there may be, use a different sentinel to detect first iteration, or just iterate over indices as shown in other answers.

If your loop makes use of `next` you might want to put the thing that absolutely has to happen at the end of each iteration into a `continue{...}` block.

```
{
  my $prev;
  foreach ( @arr ) {
    next unless defined $prev && $prev == $_;
    print "yes ($prev==$_)\n";
  }
  continue {
    $prev = $_;
  }
}
```

The outer block isn't strictly necessary; it just serves to constrain the scope of our temporary `$prev` variable.

Keep in mind that with Perl it's possible that merely accessing an element in an array could have a side effect (thanks to the magic of tied variables).  So it wouldn't necessarily be a great idea (from the standpoint of language design) for `foreach` to offer a "peek_next" feature.